# Simple form not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I run `bundle install`, run rails generate `simple_form:install` and I got this error:

`Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use rails generate simple_form:install to generate the Simple Form configuration.`

Comment: Have you restarted the rails server?

Comment: Do you have a file config/initializers/simple_form.rb?

Comment: yeah! But I got this error: uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)

Comment: add `require 'simple_form'`

Answer (score 1):

all i did was `rails generate simple_form:install` for it to remove the error